# Calculating latitude and longtitude using yaw degree and distance

Tags: distance, latitude-longitude, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

I have some drone videos and metadatas. I would like to find latitude and longtitude of center of image, if it is possible any point. To do this, I thought I can use altitude and pitch degree. Because I know hypotenuse so distance between drone and center of image is altitude multiplying 1/cos(pitch)

```
distance = altitude/cos(pitch_degree)
```

However, I dont know how to convert this distance to latitude and longtitude. What is coordinate of this point? I just know it is possible with yaw degree.

Assume I have these data:

```
Altitude:423.8
Latitude: 37.4571340229784
Longtitude: 38.6677706880851
pitch: -19.9
roll: 0
yaw: -35.2
yaw[360]: 324.8
```

Then distance is 450 meter. However, what is its latitude and longtitude?

Comment: The is a 3D variant of the Forward (aka Direct) Problem of Geodesy. There is no exact conversion because lat/lon are angular values (relative to the datum centroid). Use a geodesic function library.

Comment: @Vince I looked at what you mentioned. However, I don't know direction of drone move.